# How can I update supported PHP language level in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, settings, php-7.4

In my PhpStorm preferences, I have max PHP language level 7.3. I would like to use 7.4 but there is no 7.4 or 8.0.

How can I update all supported levels?

My PhpStorm preferences:

[image]

Comment: by updating PhpStorm itself ?

Answer (score 3):

For php 8 you must use [PhpStorm version 2020.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/12/phpstorm-2020-3-release/) or higher.